# Unity Simple Character Controller Script not working as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, position, game-development

Im scratching my head over this one, really cant figure it out.
Im trying to implement the player movement from this example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNidsMesxSE
Starts at minute 4:25 and ends at minute 5:20

This script tries translating all that to unity.So I started all the way over from scratch and just want to make a simple movement script.
You can plug this into any Unity version, throw the script onto and object with a CharacterController component, add a child object with a mesh that will tilt, the main object will rotate around its Y axis and move.

I do recommend using a simple T pose character or atleast a long capsule so you can better see what is happening than when you would be using a cube to test this.

The weird glitches im having is that the object randomly spasms out even though im always only adding extremely small rotations and movements every frame. And 95% of the time it doesnt happen, so I havent been able to pinpoint exactly what is causing this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterMove : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 200f;
public float rotationSpeed = 180f;

public float tiltFactor = 8f;

public bool normalizeVelocity = false;
CharacterController cc;
Vector3 velocity;

Transform armatureBody;


void Start()
{
    cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    armatureBody = transform.GetChild(0);
}

void Update()
{
    velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0,
                           Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if ((velocity != Vector3.zero))
    {
        var ccVelocity = cc.velocity; // CharacterController velocity. This might be the problem, but without it I cannot rotate the object towards the actual forward velocity.


        Quaternion toRotation;

        toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(ccVelocity, Vector3.up);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) print("new toRotation: " + toRotation);
        armatureBody.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(velocity.z * tiltFactor, 0, -velocity.x * tiltFactor); // Tilt Body towards velocity This causes the weirdest and most consistest twitching bugs when the tilt is backwards so the object is moving backwards, maybe because im using LookRotation to look backwards?

    }

    velocity = Quaternion.Euler(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0) * velocity; // forward is always forward

    cc.SimpleMove(velocity * Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

}

This script does 4 things,

1. get the velocity from player input.
2. rotate the main Object(this script) towards the velocity
3. add tilt towards the velocity, to the child armatureBody, this is a t Pose character in my case.
4. move the main Object this script is on.

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried removing the vector3 != Zero check, I tried normalizing the vectors, and I tried using a different Quaternion rotation method, but all with the same faulty results.

Comment: You're using `Time.deltaTime` in a fixed time step method. I could see this causing sudden jerks whenever your framerate drops. Try switching to `Time.fixeDeltaTime` and see if the issue still occurs.

Comment: Ill try taht, but thinking about this really hard last night and not being able to sleep, I now think the tilting function is absolutely solid, the real problem is the rotation towards velocity, when going backwards for example the character should turn 180 degrees, except it tries -179.98 and then 180.02, so it keeps jerking 360 degrees when it should just choose one angle either -180 or +180, because of that it actualy stays pointed forwards in that situation. I think the same is happening in other situations where glitches are occuring very rarely it must be a jump from one angle to another

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and managed to fix my issue by changing the "Min Move Distance" parameter to "0" in the Character Controller component.

Answer (score 0):

Check in Update() if Input.forward > threshold if so rotate to velocity. Dont rotate to velocity when only going sideways or backwards, so we can now strafe sideways and walk backwards when standing still or run and rotate to our velocity with the AD keys when running.

```
void Update()
{
velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0,
                       Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
if (velocity.z > 0.2f)
    {
        forwardVelocityThreshold = true;
    }
    else forwardVelocityThreshold = false;
}
```

Then in our FixedUpdate() we check for that bool and apply the rotateToVelocity if true.

Adjust the following if statement:

```
    if (ccVelocity != Vector3.zero && forwardVelocityThreshold)
        {
            toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(ccVelocity, Vector3.up);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
```

Now it works as intended, I also changed the deltaTime to FixedDeltaTime as suggested by Voidsay in the comments, although I have heard conflicting things about this. Some say FixedUpdate always uses fixedDeltaTime even if you are using deltaTime, other say no, always use fixedDeltaTime in FixedUpdate.

Comment: I didn't know it, but the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) say that deltaTime is indeed returning the value of fixedDeltaTime in  FixedUpdate
> When this is called from inside MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate, it returns Time.fixedDeltaTime.